# docker build doesn't copy css files

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.16.0-alpine as build-stage
RUN npm install -g sass
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app/
RUN ls -R > /app/test.txt
RUN sass style/style.scss style/style.css
...
```

Where `Dockerfile` is, there is `lib` directory which contains `js`, `css` files.

Problem is that container run with `docker run -it image bash`
doesn't contains `css` file that should be copied like other files.
All `*.css` are missing at `build-stage`.

host:

```
./lib:
7dbc442bb4.js      
bootstrap.min.js           
bootstrap-select.min.bin  
bootstrap-select.min.js  
jquery-3.5.0.min.js  
test.min.bin
bootstrap.min.css  
bootstrap-select1.min.bin  
bootstrap-select.min.css  
google-fonts.css         
popper.min.js
```

container (test.txt from container):

```
./lib:
7dbc442bb4.js
bootstrap-select.min.bin
bootstrap-select.min.js
bootstrap-select1.min.bin
bootstrap.min.js
jquery-3.5.0.min.js
popper.min.js
test.min.bin
```

I face this problem on github actions scripts. On my computer works correct.

Comment: try without caching, adding: `--no-cache=true`

Comment: @Henry dir is correct@Jelle I've checked but didn't help. Build is on github so it start from clean environment. I can add that on my local host it works

Comment: is there a `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: @Stefano there is no .dockerignore

Comment: Are those files checked into git? `.gitignore`?

Comment: @userAA have you solved it yet ?